# kdb/Q How to store iteration # and inputs/output?

Tags: data-structures, storage, kdb

This is more of a theoretical question, as I haven't written any code just yet.

I'm trying to iterate on a function that is supposed to output some value.

What I need is to somehow record the iteration # along with the inputs and result of the iteration function.

For example, if I am iterating on the Pythagorean function, I would like the following to output:

| Iteration # | Inputs | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0, 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1, 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1, 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 2, 3 | 5 |
| 5 | 3, 5 | 8 |

I wonder how I can store these 3 different values in kdb, I know Python and other languages have many options but I don't know if this is possible in this language.

Also, if the input variable is a table, would that impact the ability to store in any way? What about if there would be 100,000 iterations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To iterate the inputs, you can use an [accumulator](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/accumulators/):

```
q)0N!inputs:{last[x],sum x}\[5;0 1];
(0 1;1 1;1 2;2 3;3 5;5 8)
q)([] Iteration:1+til count inputs; Inputs:inputs; Output:sum each inputs)
Iteration Inputs Output
-----------------------
1         0 1    1
2         1 1    2
3         1 2    3
4         2 3    5
5         3 5    8
6         5 8    13
```

Another way is to accumulate a dict which forms a table:

```
q)i:`iter`in`out!(1;0 1;1)
q){x[`iter]+:1;x[`in]:x[`in;1],sum x`in;x[`out]:sum x`in;x}\[5;i]
iter in  out
------------
1    0 1 1
2    1 1 2
3    1 2 3
4    2 3 5
5    3 5 8
6    5 8 13
```

Comment: To elaborate on this answer, you are asking how to solve a classical iteration problem called "aggregation". Generic aggregation is sometimes called fold (or super-fold) but also known as "reduce" (as in, map-reduce) and also known as accumulation (because you are accumulating state). Knowing what the problem structure is called helps in researching tangential problems. Further, you may want to research "dynamic programming", which utilizes the result of prior steps to speedup computational complexity of an algorithm.

Comment: https://thinqkdb.wordpress.com/adverbs-part-2/ may be useful, too

Answer (score 2):

Same as Maurice but with local dict

```
q){`iter`in`out!(1+x`iter;a;sum a:last[x`in],x`out)}\[4;`iter`in`out!(1;0 1;1)]
iter in  out
------------
1    0 1 1
2    1 1 2
3    1 2 3
4    2 3 5
5    3 5 8
```